# Thompson sampling when the reward is not simply one

Tags: python, sampling, multiarmed-bandit, thompson-sampling

I am trying to implement a simple simulation of Thompson sampling for pricing inspired by Python code from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1R5QiVlF6w08dyQmTE6AoBi-TfjOoXcSk#scrollTo=8HDhqWdzi2oD). Another very similar/realted post can be found [here](https://www.mlq.ai/ai-for-ecommerce-thompson-sampling/).

The idea is that I have different conversation rates and prices (i.e. revenue the actual reward!) are inversely related.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random 

np.random.seed(42)   
number_of_slot_machines = 5
number_of_turns = 10000

number_of_positive_rewards = np.zeros(number_of_slot_machines)
number_of_negative_rewards = np.zeros(number_of_slot_machines)
reward_dollars = np.zeros(number_of_slot_machines)

conversion_rates = np.random.uniform(0.01, 0.15, number_of_slot_machines)
conversion_rates.sort()
conversion_rates = np.flip(conversion_rates)

for i in range(number_of_slot_machines):
  reward_dollars[i] = 100 + (i*10)
  print('Conversion rate for slot machine {0}: {1:.2%}'.format(i, conversion_rates[i]))
  print('Reward for slot machine {0}: {1}'.format(i, reward_dollars[i]))
```

Here is the inverse relationship produced by the above Python code:

```
Conversion rate for slot machine 0: 14.31%
Reward for slot machine 0: 100.0
Conversion rate for slot machine 1: 11.25%
Reward for slot machine 1: 110.0
Conversion rate for slot machine 2: 9.38%
Reward for slot machine 2: 120.0
Conversion rate for slot machine 3: 6.24%
Reward for slot machine 3: 130.0
Conversion rate for slot machine 4: 3.18%
Reward for slot machine 4: 140.0
```

My thinking is that there are people with different willingness to pay but obviously most people will convert for a lower price (ignoring the fact that some people are suspicious reg. prices being too low).

Now I setup some potential outcomes based on the conversion rates:

```
np.random.seed(42)
outcomes = np.zeros((number_of_turns, number_of_slot_machines)) 
for turn_index in range(number_of_turns): 
    for slot_machine_index in range(number_of_slot_machines): 
        if np.random.rand() <= conversion_rates[slot_machine_index]:
            outcomes[turn_index][slot_machine_index] = 1

#display the first 15 rows of data
print(outcomes[0:5, 0:number_of_slot_machines]) 
for i in range(number_of_slot_machines):
  print('Mean for column {0}: {1:.2%}'.format(i, np.mean(outcomes[:, i])))
```

The means come close to the "simulated truth" (obviously we can increase number_of_turns):

```
Mean for column 0: 14.53%
Mean for column 1: 11.66%
Mean for column 2: 9.48%
Mean for column 3: 6.40%
Mean for column 4: 3.42%
```

Now here comes my miserable attempt to capture the non binary rewards using the prices instead of conversation  rates:

```
rewards = np.zeros(number_of_slot_machines)
for turn_index in range(number_of_turns):
    index_of_machine_to_play = -1
    max_beta = -1

    #determine which slot machine to play for this turn
    for slot_machine_index in range(number_of_slot_machines): #for each slot machine
        #Define the shape parameters for the beta distribution. The shape will depend on the number
        #of wins and losses that have thus far been observed for this particular slot machine.
        a = number_of_positive_rewards[slot_machine_index] + 1
        b = number_of_negative_rewards[slot_machine_index] + 1

        #Get a random value from the beta distribution whose shape is defined by the number of
        #wins and losses that have thus far been observed for this slot machine
        np.random.seed(42) 
        random_beta = np.random.beta(a, b)

        #if this is the largest beta value thus far observed for this iteration
        if random_beta > max_beta:
            max_beta = random_beta #update the maximum beta value thus far observed
            index_of_machine_to_play = slot_machine_index #set the machine to play to the current machine
    
    #play the selected slot machine, and record whether we win or lose
    if outcomes[turn_index][index_of_machine_to_play] == 1:
        number_of_positive_rewards[index_of_machine_to_play] += 1
        rewards[index_of_machine_to_play] += reward_dollars[index_of_machine_to_play]
    else:
        number_of_negative_rewards[index_of_machine_to_play] += 1

number_of_times_played = number_of_positive_rewards + number_of_negative_rewards 
for slot_machine_index in range(number_of_slot_machines): #for each slot machine
    print('Slot machine {0} was played {1} times'.format(slot_machine_index, number_of_times_played[slot_machine_index]))
    print('Slot machine {0} reward: {1}'.format(slot_machine_index, rewards[slot_machine_index]))
```

It returns this nonsense:

```
Slot machine 0 was played 127026.0 times
Slot machine 0 reward: 140400.0
Slot machine 1 was played 2395.0 times
Slot machine 1 reward: 0.0
Slot machine 2 was played 364.0 times
Slot machine 2 reward: 0.0
Slot machine 3 was played 131.0 times
Slot machine 3 reward: 0.0
Slot machine 4 was played 84.0 times
Slot machine 4 reward: 0.0
```

I would expect the algorithm to converge towards the slot machine with the highest reward but not highest conversation rate. Is there anything to achieve this in this simulation (obviously the reward update is not the correct one)? So the question is: How can I change Thompson sampling to cater for non binary rewards? Hope tis makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: Could be more suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: You sure? Requires expertise in TS....

Comment: Usually implementation issues are discussed in SO  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432060/simple-slot-machine-code-chooses-same-option-thompson-sampling  but posting here maybe also good.

Comment: Sure but it is about how to use TS in this scenario expressed as code.

Comment: Sure. All good. Question might have overlaps between two stacks, I think.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen it is a question about a reinforcement learning technique which I expressed as Python to show my attempt.

Comment: (+1) Interesting question.

Comment: It may help to describe your code more transparently in statistical terms. The inclusion of unexplained code in random computer package $X$ limits the potential for review on this site. Doing so, is, in a word, presumptuous, as each of us has a favorite list of computer implementations, which are generally not overlapping.

Comment: bit unfair to close this. it is a question on MAB expressed as a very commonly use programming language!!! It does not focus on programming!

Comment: If the focus is not on programming, then what is the question about? Is your question concerned with debugging this program, or about how to conceptually consider Thompson sampling for non-binary rewards? If the latter, please [edit] to clarify. Perhaps you'd be interested in peer-reviewed literature about Thompson sampling for non-binary rewards, or similar.

Comment: @Sycorax yes it is related to non binary reward. I will try to edit.

Comment: I updated my question and received 2 upvotes - surely this deserves re-opening (-: